# Find the sum of the series 1 + 1/2 + 1/3 ....+ 1/n, using while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my homework problem. We were asked to find the sum of the series -> 1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4 ... + 1/n (here n = 20)

The code I tried is provided below.

```
denominator=1
num=float(1/denominator)
sum=0
while denominator<=20:
    print(num)
    sum+=num
    denominator+=1
print(f'the sum of the above series is {sum}.')
```

The output is coming out to be 20. But that is not the required result.

Comment: You are not updating `num` inside the while loop while adding it to `sum`. You need to update `num` inside the while loop as `num = 1/denominator`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`1 / denominator` is already a float, so no need for `float(...)`, and assigning `1 / denominator` to `num` once doesn't mean `num` will change as `denominator` changes, so, you should calculate `1 / denominator` for each `denominator` in the loop, and avoid using built-in function `sum` (which you could have used to solve this) as a variable name:

```
denominator = 1
s = 0
while denominator <= 20:
    num = 1 / denominator
    print(num)
    s += num
    denominator += 1
print(f'the sum of the above series is {s}.')
```

Output:

```
1.0
0.5
0.3333333333333333
0.25
0.2
0.16666666666666666
0.14285714285714285
0.125
0.1111111111111111
0.1
0.09090909090909091
0.08333333333333333
0.07692307692307693
0.07142857142857142
0.06666666666666667
0.0625
0.058823529411764705
0.05555555555555555
0.05263157894736842
0.05
the sum of the above series is 3.597739657143682.
```

Using built-in `sum` with a generator expression:

```
s = sum(1 / d for d in range(1, 21))
```

Comment: After every loop it starts from while and not from the starting. Isn't?

Answer (score 2):

```
sum = 0
for i in range(1, 21):
    sum += 1.0 / i

print(sum)
```

Output:

```
3.59773965714
```

Comment: Using `sum` shadows the builtin `sum()` function, which, btw, is useful here as MrGeek mentioned: `s = sum(1 / d for d in range(1, 21))`

Comment: This is really compact but we didn't learn the use of range in python. Moreover, we were asked to solve the problem using while loop. Anyways Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The float(1/denominator) is not a function definition but it returns a value.
When you call this code it evaluate to the current value of 1/denominator = 1/1 = 1.

So in the while loop you add 1 for 20 iterations that's the reason you get 20.
Either create a function or move the logic to the loop.

```
def get_num(denominator):
    return float(1/denominator)

denominator=1
sum=0
while denominator<=20:
    sum+=get_num(denominator)
    denominator+=1
print(f'the sum of the above series is {sum}.')


denominator=1
sum=0
while denominator<=20:
    sum+=float(1/denominator)
    denominator+=1
print(f'the sum of the above series is {sum}.')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Fractions** module of python for this calculation. [Fractions](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/fraction-module-python/)

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import fractions

denominator = 1
sum = 0
while denominator<=20:
    num = fractions.Fraction(1, denominator)
    sum += num
    denominator += 1

print('the sum of the above series is :', sum)
print('the sum of the above series is :', float(sum))
```

Output:

```
the sum of the above series is : 55835135/15519504                                                                                     
the sum of the above series is : 3.597739657143682
```

Above code is tested on python2.7 and [python3](https://rextester.com/NMSZA90539).

It prints two lines. First one prints the value as fraction and second one prints the value as float.